# Direct link to specific order in control panel from front end template

Tags: expresso-store

Is there any way to generate a URL to take an administrator directly to an order from a list generated by the {exp:store:orders} tag?

I can send them here: /cp/addons_modules/show_module_cp&module=store&sc=orders (to the main orders module)

I tried "/cp/addons_modules/show_module_cp&module=store&sc=orders&sm=show&id={order_id}" but the order_id does not match the "cart id".

Am I missing a simple tag?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the conformation of a URL that you get when you visit an order in the Control Panel? Visit one and let us know.

Comment: The problem is that the Control Panel url wants the Cart ID, but the {orders} tag pair can only output the order_id. You might need an add-on (plugin), which took the order ID supplied via parameter, then searched the orders table and supplied the cart_id for that order.